# Where is the JobScape preference file located?

Tags: autosys

Is there a configuration file for JobScape where I can specify which jobs to load on startup, the refresh interval etc?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently JobScape that comes with AutoSys 4.5 has no user preference file. You can not specify default values for job specific parameters that you see from the `View` menu (like what jobs to load on startup, the view levels etc). But there is a preference file for X-Windows resources that you can manually edit to specify default values for X-Windows parameters that you see from the `Options` menu (like auto reload, refresh interval etc.) In Solaris this file is `/usr/openwin/lib/app-defaults/Xpert`